# How to validate multiple input with the same name in a class extended from FormRequest

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel.

I want to know how to validate multiple input with the same name.

I have a validation rule for a POST request but this fails the validation although I have all values required.

I noticed that the key names are not the same as the key names from user input, so I think that's causing the problem.

[image]

On the page I have a form like this, so, I have many input fields with the name like "visit[0]['did_visit']", "visit[1]['did_visit']", "visit[2]['did_visit']...

But, I can't figure out how to validate these on my class extended from FormRequest class.

Please help me!!

## VisitRecordRequest extends FormRequest

```
class VisitRecordRequest extends FormRequest
{


    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }



    public function rules()
    {

        switch($this->method())
        {

            case 'GET':

                return [];

            case 'POST':
            {

                //var_dump my input!!!
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($this->input());
                echo "</pre>";

                exit;

                return [

                    'date' => 'required',
                    'hour' => 'required',
                    'minute' => 'required',
                    'weather' => 'required',
                    'room_id' => 'required',
                    'did_visit' => 'required',
                    'bounce_zone' => 'required',
                    'bounce_reason' => 'required',
                    'next_action' => 'required',

                ];
            }

            case 'PUT':
            {
                return [];

            }

            case 'PATCH':
            {
                return [];
            }

            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }

            default:break;
        }

        return [];


    }


    public function response(array $errors)
    {

    }


}
```

## var_dump log

```
array(2) {
  ["visit"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["common"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-13"
      ["hour"]=>
      string(2) "09"
      ["minute"]=>
      string(2) "00"
      ["weather"]=>
      string(5) "sunny"
    }
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["room_id"]=>
      string(2) "33"
      ["did_visit"]=>
      string(2) "on"
      ["bounce_zone"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["bounce_reason"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["next_action"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["memo"]=>
      string(11) "hello world"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["room_id"]=>
      string(2) "34"
      ["did_visit"]=>
      string(3) "off"
      ["bounce_zone"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["bounce_reason"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["next_action"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["memo"]=>
      string(14) "hello world!!!"
    },
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["room_id"]=>
      string(2) "35"
      ["did_visit"]=>
      string(3) "off"
      ["bounce_zone"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["bounce_reason"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["next_action"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["memo"]=>
      string(14) "hello world!!!"
    }
  }
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "2yvZEmM3SUxTcUAZusZs87B1fKD4edVFy0AY4kjC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `visit => 'array'` .. then have a separate validator for visit ..

then have

```
foreach($request->visit as $visit)
{
    //validate visit ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know I can use "array" for validation type. I'll look it up!

Answer (score 3):

```
'visit.*.did_visit' => 'required'
```

Check here for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays